# React development build shows a div(button) but the production build makes it invisible

Tags: html, css, reactjs, production, invisible

I've been building a website for work and have a "Gallery" button on top of two slideshows. It works perfectly fine on the development build, but the production build doesn't show the button for some reason. I can still inspect and click it but it's just invisible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYN3X.jpg

This is what the React App.js looks like:

```
 <div>
      <div className="navbarContainer">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <div className="homePage">
            <div className="coverContainer">
              <Cover />
            </div>
            <div className="servicesButtonContainer">
              <ServicesButton />
            </div>
            <div className="introGalleryContainer">
              <SlideshowLeft />
              <SlideshowRight />
              <GalleryButton />
            </div>
            <div className="reviewsContainer">
              <Reviews />
            </div>
            <div className="infoContainer">
              <Info />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/services">
          <div className="servicesContainer">
            <Services />
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/gallery">
          <div className="galleryContainer">
            <Gallery />
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
```

This is the parent css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;

  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* z-index: 1; */
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

This is the css for the gallery part and main body (I regret writing all my css in a global file, cleaning it up will be a nightmare):

```
.introGalleryContainer .image-gallery-image {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
.introGalleryContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;

  border-bottom: thick solid white;
}
.twinSlideshow {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.galleryButtonWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 85%;

  max-width: 30%;
  min-width: 20.1%;

  margin-top: 20%;
  padding: 1.5%;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-size: 2vw;
}
.galleryButtonWrapper:hover {
  background: #353535;
}
```

I'm using a heavily modified npm slideshow.

If any more information is needed (like react component code) I'd be glad to provide that.

Any help would be very much appreciated since I'm quite perplexed as to what is causing this.

Comment: Can you add the parent of the button component?

Comment: Absolutely, I just added the entire App.js and in terms of css, it's body > .introGalleryContainer > .galleryButtonWrapper

Comment: what's the css on that invisible button? on the DOM

Comment: this is the .introGalleryContainer: https://imgur.com/S1Rk4wl

this is the .galleryButtonWrapper: https://imgur.com/49Rb2f4

and this is the .galleryButton: https://imgur.com/GTDc4zT

Answer (score 2):

So after checking every line I found the problem. Create-react-app has a known bug that changes the opacity value to 1%. A workaround is to simply use decimal values for now (until it's fixed). If you want 85% opacity, write 0.85 instead and so on.